# Prove that $4^m + 11^n = x^2$ with $(m,n,x) \in \mathbb{N}^3$ does not admit solutions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, exponential-diophantine-equations

My problem is the following :\

> Show that $4^m + 11^n = x^2$ with $(m,n,x) \in \mathbb{N}^3$ has no solution.

My first idea is to separate the problem into two cases:
when $n$ is even, and when $n$ is odd (I already used this method in similar problems). 
Then, I guess you have to look at the modulo 4 problem, but it doesn't give anything.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem ?

Lucas.

Comment: Reduction modulo $4$ forces $n$ even.

Comment: Hint: $4 = 2^2$, so factorize accordingly, and this problem is almost immediate. Further hint in white latex, highlight to view:  $\color{white} { 11^n = (x - 2^m)(x+2^m) }$

Comment: @Lucas Welcome to Math SE. Another method is to, after using Eric Tower's comment that $n$ must be even, then consider the equation modulo $3$.

Comment: Ok, so : if $n$ is odd, then $11^n \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$. So, $4^m + 11^n \equiv 3 \pmod4$, and we can easily deduce that $n$ must be even !

Comment: But then, I am a little stuck...

Comment: I am trying to do something with what Calvin Lin told me, I'll keep you informed !

Comment: To clarify, it is almost immediate if one uses Catalan's conjecture/theorem (which is an overkill for this problem). Otherwise, there's 1 more line to fill in.

Comment: I don't know much about this theorem. Currently, I prove that $n$ is even, so that $n = 2k$. Then, after some factorizations and little tricks, I have $2 \cdot 11^k = 4^x - 4^y$, where $x, y$ are some numbers such that $x+y = m$. Is this a good idea ?

Comment: K, the approach you're using is similar to what I'm thinking of, but you're instead using $ 4^m = (x - 11^k)(x+11^k)$ instead of my factorization. Note that the conclusion should be $ x \pm 11^k = 2^a, 2^b$ (it doesn't need to have the form of $4^a$. Let's also avoid our notation $x$ doing double duty). From here, can you show that $x - 11^k = 1$? Hint: What can we say if $ x - 11^k = 2^a  \mid 2^b = x+11^k$?

Comment: If $2^a | 2^b$ then $x-11^k | x+11^k$ right ?

Comment: + can the second form of Zsigmondy theorem help me solving this second part ? It might be easier, no ?

Comment: Right, can you work from there to show that $ 2^a = 1, 2$? You have the right idea of looking at $2 \times 11^k = 2^b - 2^a $. IE Is it obvious that for $ a > 1$, there are no solutions?

Comment: @Lucas Note the squares of all integers with no factors of $3$ are congruent to $1$ modulo $3$. Thus, with $4^m \equiv 1^m \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, since $n = 2k$ is even, then $11^n \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, so the left side is $3^m + 11^n \equiv 1 + 1 \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$. Finally, compare this to what the right side may be.

Comment: You don't need to use anything high power for this (but of course, you may choose to do so). Just factorization and modulus considerations are sufficient.

Comment: For $a > 1$, I mean, $2^a$ will be greater than $2$ ? It is obvious no ?

Comment: JohnOmielan, I don't know if my solution is very good, but after looking at the right side, it really helped me finishing the problem. + thanks Calvin Lin for your help :) ! Big thank you !

Comment: @Lucas Can you type up your solution and post it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have $x^2-4^m=(x-2^m)(x+2^m)=11^n$. Both $(x-2^m)$ and $(x+2^m)$ cannot be divisible by $11$ because their difference is a power of $2$. So the smaller of them is $1$, and the bigger is $11^n$: $x-2^m=1, x+2^m=11^n$. So $2^{m+1}+1=11^n$. So $11^n-1=2^{m+1}$. Hence $2^{m+1}$ is divisible by $5$, a contradiction.

Comment: Yup, this is what I was going for. OP's route in the comments will yield a similar equation at the end, but it's slightly more convoluted.

Comment: I could not follow the comments: was busy writing the answer.